# SQLAlchemy (core) NOT IN subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Without using ORM, how to append a NOT IN subquery to a SELECT query?

```
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM table_X )
```

Using Python:

```
s = select([batch_table])
```

I could always revert to raw sql, but that would be taking the easy way out ;-).

Comment: Are you looking for something like `select([table_a]).where(table_a.c.id.notin_(select([table_b.c.id])))`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160052/sqlalchemy-subquery-in-in-clause

Comment: benvc: Exactly! Works perfectly. Only weird effect is, and I noticed that before, I need to leave out the .c. part for it to work.

Comment: Then you are using ORM models, i.e. mapped/declarative classes.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct answer was given by benvc:

```
select([table_a]).where(table_a.c.id.notin_(select([table_b.c.id])))
```